# Does commmeting affect the things outside?

Tags: css

Why this code shows border 7px

```
#content_area {
position: relative;
float: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
border: 7px solid #FFFD33;
<!-- width: 125px; -->
}
```

but if I put `border: 7px solid #FFFD33;`after commeting:

```
#content_area {
position: relative;
float: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
<!-- width: 125px; -->
border: 7px solid #FFFD33;
}
```

it doesn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
<!-- width: 125px; -->
```

to

```
/* width: 125px; */
```

CSS uses different commenting and embedded HTML comments might break the declaration.

Comment: Glad it works! I believe it has something to do with the way page elements are loaded.